# resolve model before rendering template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

My issue is my data changing while template was loaded so it take 2 sec to see old data as not login user and after that it change to normal mode.
How can I prevent to render the init state?

my code from service :

```
    @Injectable()
    export class UserData {
      user = {};
      isAuth = false;

      private _changeState(user: any = null) {
        if (user) {
          this.isAuth = true;
          this.user = this._getUserInfo(user);
          this.router.navigate(['/']);

        }
        else {
          this.isAuth = false;
          this.user = {};
        }
      }

  private _getUserInfo(user: any): any {
    if (!user) {
      return {};
    }
    let data = user.auth.providerData[0];
    return {
      name: data.displayName,
      avatar: data.photoURL,
      email: data.email,
      provider: data.providerId
    };
  }
```

and the template for render user data:

```
<div *ngIf="userData.isAuth">
    <div  class="user-profile clearfix">
      <div  class="dropdown al-user-profile">

        <a class="profile-toggle-link dropdown-toggle" id="user-profile-dd" data-toggle="dropdown"
           aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="{{userData.user.avatar }}">
        </a>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!userData.isAuth" class="social-main">
      <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login In</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use the resolve feature http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Comment: The clean solution is to use a data resolver as  @PatrickJane hinted. Alternatively, wait for the data to arrive before setting `isAuth=true`. To get help on 2nd way, show us how `this._getUserInfo()` works

Comment: @BeetleJuice I update the main post

Comment: Is `user.auth.providerData[0]` synchronous? Does it fetch from the server?

Comment: sure it comes from server